# Change url to a dot url

Tags: url, web

Now this might be a very simple thing but I can't think of the right term and how to put it in to a question.

On some web sites they have a page called videos and it's like this:

> ***www.yourwebsite.com/videos***

And on other web sites they have url's that are like this instead :

> ***videos.yourwebsite.com***

I would like to know the right term for this and how to achieve it (the second example). It might have some thing to do with mapping or some thing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up subdomains. This is not something you do only from your scripts (although you may have to check which subdomain is in the url in your scripts to give the user the proper response).
Your web server provider needs to support this, and have some kind of control panel you can access to set up these subdomains.

Answer (score 2):

The second is a subdomain to yourwebsite.com.

Comment: I know it was an simple answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is a [subdomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain).

Comment: I know it was an simple answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They are named "Third level subdomains", you have to configure your server to redirect to a specify directory for example "/videos" when the subdomain "video.url.it" receive a call.